# Duplicate records and loss of primary key on MS Access table in multi-user database

Tags: database, ms-access, duplicates, multi-user, corrupt-data

Apologies if a similar question has been addressed elsewhere but I'm struggling to find the obvious answer to my issue.... 
I have rolled out a split end database (.accdb created in Access 2013) to 6 members of my team by providing each with a copy of the front end which links to a back end on a shared network drive. Four of the users are opening the db through Access 2013, one through Access Runtime 2013 and one through Runtime 2010 (32 bit).

The primary job of the database is to allow users to allocate and manage tasks for a set of campaigns. The db centres around a task table which is updated via a bound form. When new task records are created, usually via a control from a parent 'campaign' form, some fields are pre-populated.

The (frequent) bug seems to occur when a two users are editing different task records via the task form at the same time. Occasionally, one of the task records becomes corrupted (hashed out or Chinese characters!) but more often one of the tasks becomes duplicated in place of the other. This then leads to duplicate task IDs and the loss of the primary key on this field.

I have tried setting record locking to both no locks (optimistic locking) - on users' access clients (except the Runtime versions where I can't see there is an option to do this) and on the task form itself - and edit record (pessimistic locking) using the setting in the task form properties.

I am having trouble diagnosing whether the error lies with locking and/or the point at which a record is saved (currently just on form close) or whether there is a bigger weakness in the set up. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this duplication and sometimes corruption might occur? Thanks

Comment: When new task records are created in your interface, are they being added to the table directly by the form (which is how I interpret "bound form"), or are you using VBA to programmatically add the new record to the table(s)?

Comment: thanks dspitzle. they are being added directly by the form to a single table